# How to plot these two trace plots of `beta_1` in the same figure with a different color?

Tags: r, plot

If I want to get a Gibbs simpler:

```
 library(mvtnorm)

 #Pseudo Data
 #Sample Size
 n = 50

 #The response variable
 Y = matrix(rnorm(n,20))

 #The Design matrix
 X = matrix(c(rep(1,n),rnorm(n,3),rnorm(n,10)),nrow=n)
  k = ncol(X)

 #Number of samples
 B = 1100

 #Variables to store the samples in 
  beta = matrix(NA,nrow=B,ncol=k)
  sigma = c(1,rep(NA,B))
  psi = rep(NA,B)

 #The Gibbs Sampler
   for(i in 1:B){

  #The least square estimators of beta and sigma
   V = solve(t(X)%*%X)
   bhat = V%*%t(X)%*%Y

  sigma.hat = t(Y-X%*%bhat)%*%(Y-X%*%bhat)/(n-k)


  #Sample beta from the full conditional 
  beta[i,] = rmvnorm(1,bhat,sigma[i]*V)

  #Sample sigma from the full conditional
  sigma[i+1] = 1/rgamma(1,(n-k)/2,(n-k)*sigma.hat/2)

 #Obtain the marginal posterior of psi
  psi[i] = (beta[i,2]+beta[i,3])/sigma[i+1]
 }


 #Plot the traces
   dev.new()
   par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 plot(beta[,1],type='l',ylab=expression(beta[1]),main=expression("Plot of "*beta[1]))
 plot(beta[,2],type='l',ylab=expression(beta[2]),main=expression("Plot of "*beta[2]))
  plot(beta[,3],type='l',ylab=expression(beta[3]),main=expression("Plot of "*beta[2]))
plot(sigma,type='l',ylab=expression(sigma^2),main=expression("Plot of "*sigma^2))
```

Then I got the trace plot:

[image]

My question is if I run again to get another plot of `beta_1`( rep. `beta_2`). How to plot these two trace plots of `beta_1` ( rep. `beta_2`) in the same figure with a different color? I do not know how to write this code?

Comment: Why not generate everything first beforehand (especially if you already know you'll run the code again) and plot it all at one go with `ggplot()`?

Comment: @Dunois Sorry, could you explain more? I am not familiar with `ggplot()`.

Comment: @Dunois I just want to run my code three times to get more simulations for each parameter. Then I hope I can plot three times `beta_1` in the same figure with 3 colors to compare them.

Comment: See my answer then. Perhaps what I have proposed would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you can't go back to plot 1 once you have moved onto plot4. So you need to store your simulations in a list first, so wrap your simulation into a function:

```
lambda = function(){

   beta = matrix(NA,nrow=B,ncol=k)
   sigma = c(1,rep(NA,B))
   psi = rep(NA,B)

   for(i in 1:B){

   V = solve(t(X)%*%X)
   bhat = V%*%t(X)%*%Y

   sigma.hat = t(Y-X%*%bhat)%*%(Y-X%*%bhat)/(n-k)
 
   beta[i,] = rmvnorm(1,bhat,sigma[i]*V)
   sigma[i+1] = 1/rgamma(1,(n-k)/2,(n-k)*sigma.hat/2)
   psi[i] = (beta[i,2]+beta[i,3])/sigma[i+1]
   }
   return(list(beta=beta,sigma=sigma,psi=psi))
 }
```

Run them using `replicate` :

```
results = replicate(2,lambda(),simplify=FALSE)
names(results) = paste0(1:length(results))
```

Now define colors and plot:

```
cols = c("#F0545480","#30475E80")
names(cols) = c("rep1","rep2")

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 1:3){
   plot(results[[1]]$beta[,i],type='l',
   ylab = substitute(expression(beta[x]), list(x = i)),
   main = substitute(expression(beta[x]), list(x = i)),
   col = cols[1])
   lines(results[[2]]$beta[,i],col=cols[2])
}
plot(results[[1]]$sigma,type='l',ylab=expression(sigma^2),main=expression("Plot of "*sigma^2),col=cols[1])
lines(results[[2]]$sigma,type='l',ylab=expression(sigma^2),main=expression("Plot of "*sigma^2),col=cols[2])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how to change the times of simulations for each `beta_i` in the same figure under your code?

Comment: Change `2` in `results = replicate(2,lambda(),simplify=FALSE)`?

Comment: Yes.. and u need to add one more color to cols.. and you need to add something more to the for loop. The way your data is stored is not optimal for iteration

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you where I've modified your code to work as standalone functions. `my_gibbs_test_data()` creates the data that is fed to the Gibbs sampler `my_gsamp()`, and both of these functions are themselves called by `gibbs_eval_test()` which takes as input the total number of trials/runs random data and Gibbs sampling on that should be performed (alongside the inputs for the aforementioned functions). The output of all of this is the data from the sampler in the [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) format which can then be fed to `ggplot()` for plotting.

I've demonstrated this below. (I am presuming the code is fairly self-explanatory to the OP, given it's just their own code slightly repackaged.)

```
#Requisite libraries
library(mvtnorm)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)


#----
#Random data generator for the Gibbs sampler
#Returns the data as a list; [[1]] is X, [[2]] is Y
my_gibbs_test_data <- function(myn = 50, myB = 1100, yot = 20, xot1 = 3, xot2 = 10){
  #Generating test data
  Y <- matrix(rnorm(myn, yot))
  
  X <- matrix(
    c(rep(1, myn), rnorm(myn, xot1), rnorm(myn, xot2)), 
    nrow = myn)
  
  return(list(X, Y))
}
#t2 <- my_gibbs_test_data()
#----


#----
#Gibbs sampler
#This function spits out the data as a data.frame
#Easier for plotting with ggplot() down the line
my_gsamp <- function(myX, myY, myn, myB){
  
  #
  myk <- ncol(myX)
  
  #Least sq. estimators of beta and sigma
  myV <- base::solve(t(myX) %*% myX)
  b_hat <- myV %*% t(myX) %*% myY
  sig_hat <- as.numeric( ( (t(myY - myX %*% b_hat) %*% (myY - myX %*% b_hat)) / (myn - myk) ) )
  
  
  #Sample storage variables
  #Initializing all of these with same column lengths
  #The last rows of mybeta and mypsi will remain NA after
  #the calculations
  mybeta <- matrix(nrow = myB + 1, ncol = myk)
  #
  mysigma <- c(1, rep(NA, myB))
  #mysigma <- c(1, rep(NA, myB-1))
  mypsi <- rep(NA, myB + 1)
  
  #Main for loop
  for(i in 1:myB){
    #i <- 1
    mybeta[i, ] <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(1, b_hat, mysigma[i] * myV)
    mysigma[i+1] <- 1/stats::rgamma(1, (myn - myk)/2, (myn - myk) * sig_hat/2)
    mypsi[i] <- (mybeta[i, 2] + mybeta[i, 3]) / mysigma[i+1]
  }
  
  mydat <- data.frame(mybeta, mysigma, mypsi)
  names(mydat) <- c(paste0("b", 1:ncol(mybeta)), "sig", "psi")
  #mydat$index <- seq(nrow(mydat))
  
  return(mydat)
}
#tst <- my_gsamp(t2[[1]], t2[[2]], n, B)
#----


#----
#Function that replicates the Gibbs sampling locreps number of times
gibbs_eval_test <- function(locreps = 4, locn = 50, locB = 1100, locyot = 20, locxot1 = 3, locxot2 = 10){
  
  #All that this function does is calls my_gibbs_test_data() and my_gsamp()
  #as many number of times as specified by the user via locreps
  
  #locn, locB, locyot, locxot1, and locxot2 are the parameters that control the test data
  #and the Gibbs sampler itself
  
  #Note: this function returns the data in the long format
  
  for(i in 1:locreps){
    #i <- 1
    #locreps = 1
    #locn = 50
    #locB = 1100
    #locyot = 20
    #locxot1 = 3
    #locxot2 = 10
    
    loctestdat <- my_gibbs_test_data(locn, locB, locyot, locxot1, locxot2)
    
    if(i == 1){
      outdat <- my_gsamp(loctestdat[[1]], loctestdat[[2]], locn, locB)
      
      #Index for plotting
      outdat$index <- seq_along(outdat$b1)
      #Pivoting longer
      outdat %<>% pivot_longer(cols = -index, names_to = "meas_var", values_to = "meas_val")
      
      outdat$run <- rep(i, nrow(outdat))
      
    } else{
      locdat <- my_gsamp(loctestdat[[1]], loctestdat[[2]], locn, locB)
      
      #Index for plotting
      locdat$index <- seq_along(locdat$b1)
      #Pivoting longer
      locdat %<>% pivot_longer(cols = -index, names_to = "meas_var", values_to = "meas_val")
      
      locdat$run <- rep(i, nrow(locdat))
      
      #Appending to outdat
      outdat <- dplyr::bind_rows(outdat, locdat)
    }
    
  }
  
  return(outdat)
  
}
#----


#----
#Testing
t4 <- gibbs_eval_test()



#Plotting
t4 %>% 
  filter(meas_var != "psi") %>%
  ggplot(aes(color = as.factor(run))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = meas_val, x = index)) + 
  facet_wrap(~meas_var, scales = "free")

#----
```

[image: gibbsplot]

The example plot above contains data from 4 repetitions of the Gibbs sampling process (using the baked-in default values). IMHO this solution provides lots of flexibility while also permitting easy visualization.